# Get comments after the timestamp given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, mongoid

I'm following Ryan's tutorial in polling comments and works perfectly but on polling the data he used id to get only the latest comments. How can I use the timestamp to poll the latest comments only

Here's a gist link for model,controller,view,coffeescript
https://gist.github.com/silvercrow27/e08c0142af43aec39f02

Comment: timestamps represents what? `created_at` ?

Comment: mongoids default timestamp format. `updated_at`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What do your models look like? What inputs do you have and what output do you expect?

Comment: @muistooshort What im trying to do is poll the latest comments only based on the timestamp given. I'm getting the timestamp that is in the last comment via data attribute. The output I'm expecting are the comments created after the timestamp given.

Comment: So what's wrong with devkaoru's answer? Do you maybe want `gt` instead of `gte`? Do you need more filtering?

Comment: devkaoru's answer is not wrong. as just  i said in my comment in his answer if ever im the one who commented it will poll also my comment. see my create action in comment it will respond to js which will append my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `Mongoid` you'd want:

```
Post.where(:updated_at.gte => 1.hour.ago)
```

this will return you posts updated within the last hour.

Comment: will this get all the posts?

Comment: i tried your answer a little while ago but if im the one who post . it will duplicate the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
timestamp = 1432360568
Model.where(:updated_at => Time.at(timestamp))
# Model Load (20.4ms)  SELECT `models`.* FROM `models` WHERE `models`.`updated_at` = '2015-05-23 05:56:08'
```

Assuming comments belongs to posts and you want to fetch all comments for the particular post after given timestamp. This can be done like:

```
Comment.where(:post_id => post.id).where("updated_at > ?", Time.at(timestamp))
```

Comment: I need all comments not just a certain document that has that timestamp

Comment: sorry about that. all comments based on the timestamp. for example i entered the time 2015-05-23 05:56:08. i need to get all the comments after the time specified.

Comment: ill try your answer later. ut will it work if the value of timestamp is 2015-05-23%05:56:08 like that?

Comment: `"updated_at > ?"` won't work with Mongoid. The MySQL output suggests that you're confusing Mongoid with ActiveRecord, they are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean created_at as timestamp then you can use something like this

```
post = Post.order("created_at").last
```

to get recently created one

or

```
post = Post.order("updated_at").last
```

to get the recently updated one

Comment: this will get all the Post which is a bad idea.

Comment: I only need to get all the latest post through polling. for example i entered the time 2015-05-23 05:56:08. i need to get all the comments after the time specified.